# Can you reference an item labelled for imakeidx outside the index?

Tags: cross-referencing, imakeidx

The same items that are in my index I sometimes want to reference elsewhere in the text. Obviously I could use the pageref, but I'd rather have a hyperlink that zooms to the right point within the page. These are not conventional section headers, unfortunately. Does imakeidx somehow support this?

Comment: Please provide code for a minimal example demonstrating your setup so we can understand what you're trying to do.